# Strange result with a dataframe rendering using renderDataTable in R Markdown

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to use `renderDataTable` in a R Markdown document at R Studio (R 3.6.0).

This is a simple code to show the problem

```
---
title: "Datatable Sample"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

'''{r}
renderDataTable(data.frame(Mês = c("Janeiro", "Fevereiro"), Valor = c("10", "20")), options = list(
   pageLength = 10,
   searching = FALSE)
)
'''
```

How it is rendering ...

[image]

If I try the same code with renderTable(...) I got the right rendering

[image]

Is it a bug?

Comment: wouldn't that require `DT`

Comment: It's a name collision (between shiny and DT) more than a bug.  `DT::renderDataTable` should fix it. I've answered the same issue before so I added as a comment.

Comment: [shiny::dataTableOutput() requested unknown parameter warning #2653](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2653)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that is missing a call to datatable function inside the brackets of the renderDataTable function. This is because you are delivering a dataframe to the renderDataTable function which expects another form of data structure - a datatable. See the code below:

```
output$myDT <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data.frame(Mês=c("Janeiro","Fevereiro")
                           , Valor=c(10,20)))
})
```